# Nested Flex container not growing with padding

Tags: css, flexbox

I've built a row layout with Flexbox and within each row (`.card`), there are three columns, the last (`.card-links`) of which is also a Flex container. When these three columns stack as rows on mobile, the last doesn't grow with its content + padding and its height is *only* its padding.

I've found two workarounds where I can set it as margin instead, or display it as a `block` on mobile, but I'd really like to keep using padding as I have everywhere else and understand why this is happening.

HTML structure:

```
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-img four-three-img">
  <a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
 </div>
 <div class="card-info">
  <div class="event-headings">
   <a href=""><h1>Heading</h1></a>
   <a href=""><h2>Subheading</h2></a>
  </div>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="card-links">
  <div class="button-cont">
   <a class="pass-button button" href="" target="_blank" role="button">Button Text</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-img,
.card-info,
.card-links {
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}

.card-info {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.card-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: 26.7%
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card-links {
    padding: 15px 15px 45px;
  }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, if you found a way that works, use it.  But, if you really want to use padding double check your nested elements and make sure that they are in the correct order.

Comment: Can't see the problem with the code you've posted.